# Как реализовать проверку данных в акссесоре set?

Tags: c#

Как правильно реализовать проверку присваиваемых значений в акссесоре set на C#? Это имеется виду свойств. Например, проверка строки на пустоту. Прошу показать вместе с примером

Comment: Недостаточно сказать, что язык C#, важна еще технология. Windows Forms? WPF? WP7?

Comment: и что? в WinForms сеттер работает иначе чем в WPF?

Comment: В WPF присутствуют `DependencyProperties`, которые используются нескоько иначе.

Answer (score 4):

```
public string MyStringProperty
{
   get {return _myStringProperty;}
   set
   {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
      {
         _myStringProperty = value;
      }
   }
}
```

**UPD:**
Для валидации данных, вводимых в форму, желательно реализовать интерфейс [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.item.aspx) в классе, свойства которого необходимо проверять. Примеры реализации для WPF (MVVM):

[Приложения WPF с шаблоном проектирования модель-представление-модель представления](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dd419663.aspx),

[Validate your application using IDataErrorInfo](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/06/validate-your-application-using.html)

Comment: в данном случае программа  не будет требовать вводить данные, до тех пор пока пользователь не введет верные данные

Comment: Можно при неудачной проверке генерировать событие или бросать исключение.